# OPENJSON - How to extract value from JSON object saved as NVARCHAR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, open-json

There is a column `RawData` of type `NVARCHAR` which contains JSON object as strings

```
RawData 
-------------------------------------------------------
{"ID":1,--other key/value(s)--,"object":{--object1--}}
{"ID":2,--other key/value(s)--,"object":{--object2--}}
{"ID":3,--other key/value(s)--,"object":{--object3--}}
{"ID":4,--other key/value(s)--,"object":{--object4--}}
{"ID":5,--other key/value(s)--,"object":{--object5--}}
```

This JSON string is big (1kb) and currently the most used part of this json is `object`(200 bytes).

i want to extract object part of these json strings by using `OPENJSON`.and i was not able to achieve a solution but i think there is a solution.

The result that i want is:

```
RawData 
----------------
{--object1--}
{--object2--}
{--object3--}
{--object4--}
{--object5--}
```

My attempts so far

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT RawData From DATA_TB FOR JSON PATH))
```

Comment: Please add your attempt and why it is not working for you (unexpected result, error message, ...). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql) you can find the documentation with many examples.

Comment: @Sander i will but it's so basic

Comment: Any proof of personal attempt is appreciated and can be build upon.

Comment: @Sander i have put what i done so far.

Comment: Why are you converting the field to JSON only to parse it back? Why not use eg `JSON_VALUE(RawData ...)` to get the actual data you want? *What* data do you want in the first place? Post *actual* sample data and the desired results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have done what this linked said https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Mr.AF that's not what you did. You created a *new* JSON string combining all results with  `FOR JSON PATH`, then tried to parse it (and get the original data back) with OPENJSON.  If you want to extract the value stored in `someKey` you can use `SELECT JSON_QUERY(RawData,"$.someKey") from thatTable` or something similar. For scalar values you can use `JSON_VALUE`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually i am not expert on OPENJSON thanks for your nice comment.

Comment: Nobody is. I used to be a SQL Server MVP and yet I *always* have to search for functions and names. In fact, my first comment mentioned `JSON_VALUE` because I forgot it only works with scalar values. `OPENJSON` is meant to parse complex JSON strings and return their contents as a table. You'll find the functions to query and modify JSON data in [Validate, Query, and Change JSON Data with Built-in Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: BTW I expect I'll forget that distinction by tomorrow. The more experienced one is, the more one uses docs, help and man pages. There's no way to remember every HTML tag, CSS rule, Javascript framework, ASP.NET technology *and* SQL Server feature and function.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this should work for you.

**Sample data**

```
create table data_tb
(
  RawData nvarchar(max)
);

insert into data_tb (RawData) values
('{"ID":1, "key": "value1", "object":{ "name": "alfred" }}'),
('{"ID":2, "key": "value2", "object":{ "name": "bert" }}'),
('{"ID":3, "key": "value3", "object":{ "name": "cecil" }}'),
('{"ID":4, "key": "value4", "object":{ "name": "dominique" }}'),
('{"ID":5, "key": "value5", "object":{ "name": "elise" }}');
```

**Solution**

```
select d.RawData, json_query(d.RawData, '$.object') as Object
from data_tb d;
```

See it in action: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7c8699f4b0b1e40496ddddd525944d5).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
 SELECT object 
 FROM DATA_TB as dt
 CROSS APPLY
 OPENJSON(dt.RawData) with (object     nvarchar(max) as json);
```