# Storing JSON response containing array/list into database

Tags: c#, arrays, json, database, list

I am looking to take this massive JSON response containing 2 lists (hourly, daily) and store them into a database table for later references. The difficulty I face is that the amount of items in the list is so large that I would have to do an extreme amount of modeling/mapping.

Here is an example response:

```
{"lat":33.44,"lon":-94.04,"timezone":"America/Chicago","timezone_offset":-18000,"current":{"dt":1632166751,"sunrise":1632139388,"sunset":1632183355,"temp":306.19,"feels_like":310.11,"pressure":1012,"humidity":52,"dew_point":295.02,"uvi":6.13,"clouds":20,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.09,"wind_deg":160,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}]},"hourly":[{"dt":1632164400,"temp":306.47,"feels_like":309.79,"pressure":1012,"humidity":49,"dew_point":294.3,"uvi":7.62,"clouds":17,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.06,"wind_deg":192,"wind_gust":3.89,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632168000,"temp":306.19,"feels_like":310.11,"pressure":1012,"humidity":52,"dew_point":295.02,"uvi":6.13,"clouds":20,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3,"wind_deg":193,"wind_gust":3.57,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632171600,"temp":306.76,"feels_like":309.78,"pressure":1011,"humidity":47,"dew_point":293.89,"uvi":3.98,"clouds":16,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.87,"wind_deg":195,"wind_gust":3.34,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632175200,"temp":307.23,"feels_like":309.53,"pressure":1011,"humidity":43,"dew_point":292.88,"uvi":1.98,"clouds":13,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.49,"wind_deg":188,"wind_gust":3.22,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632178800,"temp":307.14,"feels_like":308.56,"pressure":1010,"humidity":40,"dew_point":291.64,"uvi":0.63,"clouds":9,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.6,"wind_deg":158,"wind_gust":3.36,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632182400,"temp":304.33,"feels_like":305.3,"pressure":1010,"humidity":46,"dew_point":291.34,"uvi":0,"clouds":6,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.18,"wind_deg":144,"wind_gust":8.57,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632186000,"temp":301.38,"feels_like":302.27,"pressure":1010,"humidity":54,"dew_point":291.33,"uvi":0,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.1,"wind_deg":154,"wind_gust":10.49,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632189600,"temp":300.34,"feels_like":301.47,"pressure":1011,"humidity":60,"dew_point":291.92,"uvi":0,"clouds":3,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.68,"wind_deg":152,"wind_gust":11.96,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632193200,"temp":299.97,"feels_like":301.14,"pressure":1012,"humidity":62,"dew_point":292.06,"uvi":0,"clouds":5,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.66,"wind_deg":166,"wind_gust":12.87,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632196800,"temp":299.47,"feels_like":299.47,"pressure":1012,"humidity":63,"dew_point":292.01,"uvi":0,"clouds":4,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.24,"wind_deg":171,"wind_gust":12.36,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632200400,"temp":298.65,"feels_like":299.01,"pressure":1012,"humidity":67,"dew_point":292.14,"uvi":0,"clouds":4,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.81,"wind_deg":169,"wind_gust":12.06,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632204000,"temp":297.84,"feels_like":298.22,"pressure":1012,"humidity":71,"dew_point":292.38,"uvi":0,"clouds":4,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.44,"wind_deg":176,"wind_gust":11.62,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632207600,"temp":297.15,"feels_like":297.56,"pressure":1012,"humidity":75,"dew_point":292.51,"uvi":0,"clouds":11,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.98,"wind_deg":181,"wind_gust":9.59,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632211200,"temp":296.52,"feels_like":296.95,"pressure":1012,"humidity":78,"dew_point":292.57,"uvi":0,"clouds":9,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.79,"wind_deg":173,"wind_gust":7.32,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632214800,"temp":296.26,"feels_like":296.74,"pressure":1013,"humidity":81,"dew_point":292.79,"uvi":0,"clouds":18,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.6,"wind_deg":181,"wind_gust":8.27,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632218400,"temp":296.99,"feels_like":297.47,"pressure":1013,"humidity":78,"dew_point":293.03,"uvi":0,"clouds":38,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.12,"wind_deg":193,"wind_gust":7.88,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632222000,"temp":297.11,"feels_like":297.6,"pressure":1014,"humidity":78,"dew_point":293.2,"uvi":0,"clouds":50,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.04,"wind_deg":200,"wind_gust":6.44,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632225600,"temp":297.02,"feels_like":297.55,"pressure":1015,"humidity":80,"dew_point":293.27,"uvi":0,"clouds":55,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.23,"wind_deg":210,"wind_gust":6.69,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632229200,"temp":297.63,"feels_like":298.17,"pressure":1015,"humidity":78,"dew_point":293.62,"uvi":0.2,"clouds":58,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.04,"wind_deg":206,"wind_gust":6.87,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632232800,"temp":300.07,"feels_like":301.79,"pressure":1016,"humidity":69,"dew_point":294.04,"uvi":0.95,"clouds":60,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.2,"wind_deg":231,"wind_gust":6.46,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632236400,"temp":302.59,"feels_like":304.95,"pressure":1017,"humidity":60,"dew_point":294.04,"uvi":2.49,"clouds":52,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.2,"wind_deg":254,"wind_gust":6.39,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632240000,"temp":303.62,"feels_like":306.05,"pressure":1017,"humidity":56,"dew_point":293.92,"uvi":4.32,"clouds":59,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.14,"wind_deg":265,"wind_gust":5.84,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632243600,"temp":305.38,"feels_like":307.69,"pressure":1017,"humidity":49,"dew_point":293.6,"uvi":6.07,"clouds":54,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.93,"wind_deg":286,"wind_gust":5.33,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632247200,"temp":306.35,"feels_like":308.46,"pressure":1016,"humidity":45,"dew_point":293.12,"uvi":7.01,"clouds":54,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.76,"wind_deg":308,"wind_gust":5.19,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632250800,"temp":306.01,"feels_like":307.85,"pressure":1016,"humidity":45,"dew_point":292.52,"uvi":6.93,"clouds":43,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":5.9,"wind_deg":319,"wind_gust":5.42,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"pop":0.17},{"dt":1632254400,"temp":305.01,"feels_like":306.37,"pressure":1016,"humidity":46,"dew_point":292,"uvi":5.57,"clouds":70,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":5.91,"wind_deg":332,"wind_gust":6.09,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.22},{"dt":1632258000,"temp":304.41,"feels_like":305.61,"pressure":1016,"humidity":47,"dew_point":291.84,"uvi":3.61,"clouds":73,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":7.22,"wind_deg":338,"wind_gust":6.73,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.29},{"dt":1632261600,"temp":301.13,"feels_like":302.25,"pressure":1017,"humidity":57,"dew_point":291.75,"uvi":1.84,"clouds":64,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":7.39,"wind_deg":346,"wind_gust":7.51,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.29},{"dt":1632265200,"temp":299.64,"feels_like":299.64,"pressure":1018,"humidity":60,"dew_point":291.16,"uvi":0.58,"clouds":65,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":5.96,"wind_deg":357,"wind_gust":8.86,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"pop":0.26,"rain":{"1h":0.13}},{"dt":1632268800,"temp":298.65,"feels_like":298.82,"pressure":1018,"humidity":60,"dew_point":290.41,"uvi":0,"clouds":69,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.44,"wind_deg":11,"wind_gust":9.04,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.35},{"dt":1632272400,"temp":296.9,"feels_like":296.95,"pressure":1019,"humidity":62,"dew_point":289.28,"uvi":0,"clouds":94,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.24,"wind_deg":12,"wind_gust":7.81,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632276000,"temp":296.12,"feels_like":295.88,"pressure":1020,"humidity":54,"dew_point":285.91,"uvi":0,"clouds":87,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.99,"wind_deg":353,"wind_gust":11.49,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0.01},{"dt":1632279600,"temp":295.93,"feels_like":295.26,"pressure":1021,"humidity":38,"dew_point":280.77,"uvi":0,"clouds":91,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":6.2,"wind_deg":6,"wind_gust":13.17,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632283200,"temp":294.76,"feels_like":293.94,"pressure":1022,"humidity":37,"dew_point":279.63,"uvi":0,"clouds":92,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":5.94,"wind_deg":11,"wind_gust":12.65,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632286800,"temp":293.34,"feels_like":292.43,"pressure":1023,"humidity":39,"dew_point":279.06,"uvi":0,"clouds":85,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":5.31,"wind_deg":15,"wind_gust":13,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632290400,"temp":291.26,"feels_like":290.28,"pressure":1023,"humidity":44,"dew_point":278.84,"uvi":0,"clouds":74,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.93,"wind_deg":19,"wind_gust":10.82,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632294000,"temp":289.53,"feels_like":288.5,"pressure":1023,"humidity":49,"dew_point":278.75,"uvi":0,"clouds":19,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.36,"wind_deg":12,"wind_gust":8.58,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632297600,"temp":288.48,"feels_like":287.43,"pressure":1023,"humidity":52,"dew_point":278.7,"uvi":0,"clouds":37,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.32,"wind_deg":8,"wind_gust":9.27,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632301200,"temp":287.62,"feels_like":286.53,"pressure":1023,"humidity":54,"dew_point":278.56,"uvi":0,"clouds":29,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.98,"wind_deg":13,"wind_gust":7.88,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632304800,"temp":287.24,"feels_like":286.14,"pressure":1024,"humidity":55,"dew_point":278.38,"uvi":0,"clouds":22,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.85,"wind_deg":17,"wind_gust":6.39,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632308400,"temp":287.04,"feels_like":285.92,"pressure":1024,"humidity":55,"dew_point":278.21,"uvi":0,"clouds":17,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.72,"wind_deg":21,"wind_gust":5.16,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632312000,"temp":286.71,"feels_like":285.56,"pressure":1025,"humidity":55,"dew_point":278.05,"uvi":0,"clouds":15,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.4,"wind_deg":15,"wind_gust":3.67,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632315600,"temp":288.29,"feels_like":287.22,"pressure":1025,"humidity":52,"dew_point":278.7,"uvi":0.19,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":2.36,"wind_deg":1,"wind_gust":5.16,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632319200,"temp":292.03,"feels_like":291.04,"pressure":1026,"humidity":41,"dew_point":278.75,"uvi":0.93,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.04,"wind_deg":8,"wind_gust":5.45,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632322800,"temp":295.11,"feels_like":294.25,"pressure":1026,"humidity":34,"dew_point":278.7,"uvi":2.42,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.2,"wind_deg":9,"wind_gust":5.58,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632326400,"temp":297.64,"feels_like":296.88,"pressure":1026,"humidity":28,"dew_point":278.16,"uvi":4.41,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":3.6,"wind_deg":15,"wind_gust":6.48,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632330000,"temp":299.35,"feels_like":299.35,"pressure":1025,"humidity":24,"dew_point":277.39,"uvi":6.21,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.42,"wind_deg":14,"wind_gust":7.43,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1632333600,"temp":300.78,"feels_like":299.67,"pressure":1024,"humidity":21,"dew_point":276.61,"uvi":7.17,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":4.81,"wind_deg":15,"wind_gust":6.83,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"pop":0}],"daily":[{"dt":1632160800,"sunrise":1632139388,"sunset":1632183355,"moonrise":1632184260,"moonset":1632137580,"moon_phase":0.5,"temp":{"day":306.19,"min":293.46,"max":307.23,"night":299.47,"eve":304.33,"morn":293.46},"feels_like":{"day":309.23,"night":299.47,"eve":305.3,"morn":294.05},"pressure":1012,"humidity":49,"dew_point":294.05,"wind_speed":4.68,"wind_deg":152,"wind_gust":12.87,"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":12,"pop":0.5,"uvi":7.83},{"dt":1632247200,"sunrise":1632225827,"sunset":1632269672,"moonrise":1632272340,"moonset":1632227580,"moon_phase":0.52,"temp":{"day":306.35,"min":294.76,"max":306.35,"night":294.76,"eve":298.65,"morn":297.02},"feels_like":{"day":308.46,"night":293.94,"eve":298.82,"morn":297.55},"pressure":1016,"humidity":45,"dew_point":293.12,"wind_speed":7.39,"wind_deg":346,"wind_gust":13.17,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":54,"pop":0.35,"rain":0.13,"uvi":7.01},{"dt":1632333600,"sunrise":1632312267,"sunset":1632355988,"moonrise":1632360360,"moonset":1632317460,"moon_phase":0.56,"temp":{"day":300.78,"min":286.71,"max":302.15,"night":289.48,"eve":295.84,"morn":286.71},"feels_like":{"day":299.67,"night":288.37,"eve":294.9,"morn":285.56},"pressure":1024,"humidity":21,"dew_point":276.61,"wind_speed":5.31,"wind_deg":15,"wind_gust":13,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":7.17},{"dt":1632420000,"sunrise":1632398707,"sunset":1632442304,"moonrise":1632448440,"moonset":1632407340,"moon_phase":0.59,"temp":{"day":299.7,"min":285.05,"max":301.29,"night":290.51,"eve":295.23,"morn":285.05},"feels_like":{"day":299.7,"night":289.53,"eve":294.38,"morn":283.91},"pressure":1021,"humidity":23,"dew_point":277.14,"wind_speed":3.41,"wind_deg":49,"wind_gust":4.23,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":7.36},{"dt":1632506400,"sunrise":1632485147,"sunset":1632528621,"moonrise":1632536640,"moonset":1632497160,"moon_phase":0.62,"temp":{"day":301.42,"min":285.39,"max":302.98,"night":292,"eve":296.67,"morn":285.39},"feels_like":{"day":300.23,"night":291.22,"eve":296.02,"morn":284.39},"pressure":1020,"humidity":25,"dew_point":279.56,"wind_speed":2.74,"wind_deg":114,"wind_gust":4.03,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":1,"pop":0,"uvi":7.26},{"dt":1632592800,"sunrise":1632571587,"sunset":1632614938,"moonrise":1632624960,"moonset":1632586980,"moon_phase":0.65,"temp":{"day":304.56,"min":287.79,"max":307.49,"night":295.72,"eve":300.9,"morn":287.79},"feels_like":{"day":302.69,"night":295.13,"eve":299.98,"morn":286.82},"pressure":1014,"humidity":22,"dew_point":280.25,"wind_speed":3.83,"wind_deg":178,"wind_gust":11.48,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"clouds":32,"pop":0,"uvi":8},{"dt":1632679200,"sunrise":1632658027,"sunset":1632701255,"moonrise":1632713580,"moonset":1632676800,"moon_phase":0.68,"temp":{"day":307.37,"min":290.17,"max":309.91,"night":296.97,"eve":302.32,"morn":290.17},"feels_like":{"day":305.34,"night":296.48,"eve":300.95,"morn":289.52},"pressure":1014,"humidity":20,"dew_point":281.29,"wind_speed":4.48,"wind_deg":242,"wind_gust":8.12,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":3,"pop":0,"uvi":8},{"dt":1632765600,"sunrise":1632744468,"sunset":1632787572,"moonrise":1632802500,"moonset":1632766620,"moon_phase":0.71,"temp":{"day":306.2,"min":290.08,"max":308.09,"night":295.93,"eve":301.13,"morn":290.08},"feels_like":{"day":304.48,"night":295.65,"eve":300.43,"morn":289.47},"pressure":1017,"humidity":24,"dew_point":283.13,"wind_speed":3.27,"wind_deg":55,"wind_gust":5.93,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}],"clouds":0,"pop":0,"uvi":8}]}
```

The data model looks like:

```
        [JsonProperty("lat", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? Lat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lon", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public double? Lon { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timezone", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Timezone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timezone_offset", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? TimezoneOffset { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("current", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Current Current { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hourly", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<Hourly> Hourly { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("daily", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<Daily> Daily { get; set; }
```

I am using EF Core and .NET Core to build this application (just for fun). I have looked into the data annotation [ComplexType] but it no longer is supported by EF Core, and then I moved towards [Owned] and haven't had any success using that. This project is code-first.

I'm open to any advice or suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at :https://stackoverflow.com/q/63884910/6071729

Comment: Assuming you don't care about actually parsing the data, you can just store the whole json into a column.  Otherwise, if you need the data formatted to be easily query-able,  then I don't see how you can avoid creating object/table mappings for each element of the json document.

Comment: @BrandonKramer I care about parsing the data and having it available to use/manipulate. I just know there's a way to use [Owned] or [ComplexType] and I'm not doing it properly.

Comment: @AFarmanbar This would be fine if I decided to do inline SQL, but I'm trying to avoid that.